# Spring boot with thymeleaf starter excludes javassist from other dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-starter

I have 2 project, the 1st project is depending on `javassist` and 2nd project is dependint on the 1st and spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf.

The build gradle is like below
1st project

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.javassist:javassist:3.27.0-GA'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

The 2nd project is like below, `:bar:hoge` is the 1st project.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':bar:hoge')
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'com.example.koji.Main'
}
```

If I run the `../gradlew dependencyInsight --dependency javassist --configuration runtimeClasspath`, The result is like below.

```
No dependencies matching given input were found in configuration ':foo:bar:runtimeClasspath'
```

And `gradlew assemble` doesn't have javassist.

But If I removed `id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'` from 1st project or `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'` from 2nd project, then same command will return like below

```
org.javassist:javassist:3.27.0-GA
\--- project :bar:hoge
     \--- runtimeClasspath
```

And `gradlew assemble` jar has javassist.

Any ideas? Now I need to add javassist dependency at 2nd project explicitly to solve it.
Working project https://github.com/kojilin/example-multi

Comment: I got the story about `javassist `, but what is problem do you need help with?

Comment: It's weird for me that I need to add javassist dependency at 2nd project. So I want to know why it happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the reason comes from here?

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1473#issuecomment-413333723

so if I applied

```
dependencyManagement {
    applyMavenExclusions = false
}
```

It will preserve the library in runtimeClasspath.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically inherit the `javassist` dependency from `:bar:hoge`, declare it as [api](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation), not `implementation`.

Comment: My idea is not to expose javassist api. If  `foo:bar` is depending on `:bar:hoge` and  `:bar:hoge` is depending(eve use implementation) on javassist, should the final jar(runtimeClasspath) should have javassist ?

Comment: @kojilin Once you said "_It's weird for me that I need to add javassist dependency at 2nd project._", then you say "_My idea is not to expose javassist api_". Make up your mind.

Comment: I don't get it, but thanks for your comment. If I'm adding `implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'` in 1st project, even I don't add in 2nd project, in 2nd project's  runtimeClasspath we still can see guava.